# Clean way to close splashscreen in kivy after a delay

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy, if you have a `ScreenManager` with multiple screens already added, you can not change screens with the [switch_to](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) *function*, as that also tries to first add the Screen to the Screenmanager, before switching to it.

Instead, you switch screens simply by setting the `current` property, like this:

```
screenmanager.current = "new_screen_name"
```

The problem is, I wish my `SplashScreen` to automatically transition to `MainScreen` after a short delay, using `Clock.schedule_once()`.  But that can only take a function as a parameter, so I I have to write a another function just to change screen, like this:

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(switch_to_main_screen, 3)

    def switch_to_main_screen(self, *args):
        self.current = "main_screen
```

I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? e.g can I somhow directly set the "self.current" property in Clock.schedule_once?  Or, generally speaking, is there a better way to do this simple task? (i.e have a parameter be set a few seconds in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setattr()` python built-in. Try replacing:

```
Clock.schedule_once(switch_to_main_screen, 3)
```

with:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: setattr(self, 'current', 'main_screen'), 3)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this, its my ready sheet in kivy:

```
import #what u need

Builder.load_file('the.kv')
      

class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        

class secscreen(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        pass


class thscreen(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

            
class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() 

        self.fscreen = fscreen()                 ## as default this is my 
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")   #   my first screen
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)          # if i want second screen
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)          # as first i move this below
                                                 ##  secscreen its waay
        self.secscreen = secscreen()             ###    efficient
        screen  = Screen(name = "secondscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.secscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.thscreen = thscreen()
        screen  = Screen(name = "thirdscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.thscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
theapp = theapp()    
theapp.run()
```

This way the fscreen is by default the first screen after the presplash